# How to access the current page from within a DD4T component view

Tags: 2011, dd4t

Due to an irritatingly structured HTML design, I need to (in my 2011 SP1 DD4T .NET web application) be able to access certain Component Presentations on a page from within a Component view, to embed one CP within another.

I cannot use the ViewBag to pass the current IPage object around, as the CPs are rendered in a sub action, and the ViewBag is not shared across different actions.

I was poking around and saw I could probably make a custom ComponentPresentationRenderer and ComponentController which enable me to pass the page as a parameter to the sub action, but before I do this, is there a way to do this without this level of customization?

Comment: The ComponentPresentation has a Page property, which should give access to the entire page. Isn't that working for you?

Comment: DOH! Thanks Q. I knew there had to be a simple answer...

Comment: I posted it as an answer now so it can be approved for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ComponentPresentation has a Page property, which gives access to the entire page.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: see Quirijn's answer for this situation but I'm going to leave the below approach a for different situation.

One way I've achieved this (not in exactly the same situation - this was to find settings for a form after a POST and this is a little hacky) is to use the current url to look up the page from DD4T's PageFactory, since this is how DD4T found the page it's pretty reliable and the IPage object should be cached. I was using the Referrer but it should work just as well with the current Url.

Here's our code:

```
string url = UriHelper.ParseUrl(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
var page = PageFactory.FindPage(url);
```