# Accessing Page Model Metadata from Entity View in DXA

Tags: dxa

Is it possible to access the `PageModel` metadata from an Entity View level?  I don't see any properties on the entity model `@Model` that expose the `PageModel` or Page Metadata.

I've seen [this post about DD4T](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/how-to-access-the-current-page-from-within-a-dd4t-component-view), in DD4T the `ComponentPresentation.Page` property gives access to the whole page. Does DXA have something similar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The page model is available in an entity view though the `WebRequestContext`.

```
@WebRequestContext.PageModel
```

It is considered bad practice though to use page data in your entity view. It is code smell, sounds like the content model is not ideal.

The page metadata fields are available as well in `PageModel.Meta`.

```
@WebRequestContext.PageModel.Meta["description"]
```

Even better, you can make your own strongly typed model add properties for the metadata fields you would like to use.

*Edit: added page model metadata.*

Comment: The standard Page Model does have a `Meta` property which also provides (loosely typed) access to Page metadata, but it is indeed better to create your own strongly typed Page Model class and use senantic mapping to the Page metadata.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I never used the `PageModel.Meta`. The answer is updated with this info.