# DXA StructureGroup Metadata

Tags: dxa

Do we have the Structure Group Metadata available within DXA?

For Navigation I understand I could extend the DXA Navigation TBB, and extend DXA to get this data.

Could I build a custom TBB to publish the Structure Group metadata into the JSON?

However, if I wanted to access the Structure Group metadata from within a Page, would I be able to extend the default DXA TBBs to output the Structure Group Metadata as part of the Page?  But then if the Structure Group Metadata changes, we'd need to re-publish all Pages.

Or what if I publish a separate JSON for navigation and the a Structure Group and a pointer to the Structure Group from the Page JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it would help in your case, but I do recall that there is a DD4T template `InheritMetadataPage` and `InheritMetadataComponent` that merges metadata fields from it's parent folders or structure groups in the published component or page. Is this something you could use in your case ?

see https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates/blob/develop/source/DD4T.Templates/InheritMetadataPage.cs and https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates/blob/develop/source/DD4T.Templates/InheritMetadataComponent.cs .

Off course, this doesn't solve your problem that you need to republish all pages if a structuregroup metadata item changes.

Comment: Good point about mentioning the fact that inheriting content from a Structue Group can create a dependency to a lot of Pages, which has a huge impact on Publishing.

Answer (score 2):

The Structure Group itself was not available in DXA 1.x at all for Pages if I recall correctly, for DXA 2 (in the R2 data model) we have added it as part of the DXA/DD4T merge.

That still doesn't directly expose Structure Group metadata, I think we only have the ID available.

I think the most fitting answer is similar to your other [question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17860/accessing-page-model-metadata-from-entity-view-in-dxa), which is to make your own strongly typed model, and add properties for the metadata fields you would like to use.